# how to convert all pdf to json in one api call using Google Vision api

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vision

i have written below code in C# for converting pdf into json using Google vision api.
Api doing one pdf at a time in one call, and i have hundreds of thousands of pdf files. It's very time consuming process.

I want to know is there a way to process all pdfs in one batch rather than separate api call for each pdf to convert?

```
var asyncRequest = new AsyncAnnotateFileRequest
            {
                InputConfig = new InputConfig
                {
                    GcsSource = new GcsSource
                    {
                        Uri = gcsSourceUri
                    },
                    // Supported mime_types are: 'application/pdf' and 'image/tiff'
                    MimeType = "application/pdf"
                },
                OutputConfig = new OutputConfig
                {
                    // How many pages should be grouped into each json output file.
                    BatchSize = 2,
                    GcsDestination = new GcsDestination
                    {
                        Uri = $"gs://{gcsDestinationBucketName}/Converted/{gcsDestinationPrefixName}"
                    }
                }
            };

            asyncRequest.Features.Add(new Feature
            {
                Type = Feature.Types.Type.DocumentTextDetection
            });

            List<AsyncAnnotateFileRequest> requests =
                new List<AsyncAnnotateFileRequest>();
            requests.Add(asyncRequest);

            var operation = client.AsyncBatchAnnotateFiles(requests);

            //Console.WriteLine("Waiting for the operation to finish");

            operation.PollUntilCompleted();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the async method, so you don't have to wait for the operation to complete. Remove this line: operation.PollUntilCompleted();

Just send all your requests in and make sure each request specifies a unique destination.